# rails server does not start in 3.2.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm

After installing **RVM** (which automatically upgrade my ruby to 1.9.3 and rails to 3.2.9), `rails server` or `rails s` does not start the server in **Rails 3.2.9**, but just print out the documentation with Usage and Options.

I use the old method of `ruby script/server`, but then I receive error:

> /Users/FooUser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in
>   `require': cannot load such file -- script/../config/boot (LoadError)
>     from
>   /Users/FooUser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`
>   require'     from script/server:2:in `'

...Everything just broke apart after I install RVM..

Comment: just guess, you may need to install rails inside rvm.

Comment: After install rvm you can install other ruby version. $ rvm install ruby-1.8.7 and create a gemset with a specific rails version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`script/server` is the old old old way of doing it. `script/server` doesn't exist within Rails 3+ apps. `script/rails` is the way now.

If `rails` is just printing out the docs, it's because this file doesn't exist. That would lead me into thinking that the application you're attempting to run this on **isn't** a Rails 3 app.

Answer (score 0):

> but just print out the documentation with Usage and Options.

Are you sure that you're in Rails app directory? It seems Rails can't find application files in the directory where you're trying to start server from.